# Triggering function on ngclick with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a function that makes a $http call to an external API and then populates some results within an ng-repeat array.

Right now the function gets triggered on every element on the ng-repeat, which creates a whole lot of server calls. I'd like for the function to only make the call once an element from the ng-repeat is clicked upon.

I've tried with ng-click, but i'd say i'm missing something.

The $http query that i'm trying to call on click is the second one:

```
function ImageCtrl($scope, $http) {
      $scope.image = 'img/record-default.png'; 
      $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + $scope.artist.name + '&album=' + $scope.release.title + '&format=json').
        success(function (data4) {
          $scope.image = data4.album.image[2]['#text'];
        }
      )

    function getVersions ($scope, $http){    
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/masters/' + $scope.release.id + '/versions').
        success(function (data5) {
          $scope.versions = data5.versions;
      });
  }   

}
```

And the relevant html:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="ImageCtrl" ng-repeat="release in releases | filter:album | filter:year | filter:{ role: \'main\' }" > 
  <div class="release" ng-click="getVersions()"> \
     <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{image}}" /> {{release.title}} 
        <ul ng-controller="ImageCtrl">
           <li ng-repeat="version in versions">{{version.format}}</li>
        </ul>            
  </div> 
</div>
```

And a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0aYg1TbnRFwW1WhuPKYp?p=preview). Function in question is line 60 on script.js

Comment: May be I have understood the questions wrong. Why wouldn't you just move ng-click='getVersions()' to li?

Comment: @Thara col-md-3 is already an ng-repeat listing some elements. Upon a click on one of these elements, I want to call the getVersions function and populate the UL (one for each col-md-3 element)

Comment: Is that Plunkr complete? It doesn't look like you are even registering your controllers.

Comment: @Josh I started learning Angular 2 weeks ago, looong way to go still : )

Comment: @EricMitjans - Ok. So... not to get you down but there are a whole bunch of things wrong with your implementation. Give me a little bit of time and I'll refactor your Plunkr. Going to be longer than 5 minutes ;)

Comment: @Josh i'm lacking a bit the basic understanding of concepts and best practice, product of being more prone to hands on than to read endless tutorials. I'm very aware of this, and that eventually i'll have to swallow a proper js book... If u refactor the code i'll really appreciate it, I'm sure it'd throw some light in some concepts that i'm still missing...

Comment: @EricMitjans - I'm working through it now. Should help me pinpoint issues with the code.

Comment: @EricMitjans - Here is the fully refactored Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/6R3zEX?p=preview

Comment: @Josh much appreciated! I'll take a deep look comparing the 2 versions and trying to understand the why of the rework. May I send u a msg if some question arises? If not is completely ok, you did more than enough!!

Comment: @EricMitjans - Absolutely. I'm happy to answer any questions you might have.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up taking what you have shown and doing some refactoring.

I moved `getVersions` to the prototype, and use it to append versions to a release object instead of the `$scope`.

```
function ImageCtrl($scope, fakeService) {
  var _this = this;
  this.fakeService = fakeService;
  this.$scope = $scope;

  fakeService.getReleases()
      .then(function (releases) {
      $scope.releases = releases;
  });

  this.$scope.getVersions = function(release){
      _this.getVersions(release);
  };
}

ImageCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'fakeService'];

ImageCtrl.prototype.getVersions = function (release) {
  this.fakeService.getVersions(release.id)
      .then(function (versions) {
      release.versions = versions;
  });
};
```

The markup isn't terribly different, but you can see where I pass the actual `release` object into the `getVersions` function in the click event. This way it always acts directly on the object bound to that particular row.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ImageCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="release in releases">
        <div class="release" ng-click="getVersions(release)">
            <h1>{{release.title}}</h1>
            <img class="img-responsive" height="100" width="100" ng-src="{{release.image}}" />
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="version in release.versions">{{version.format}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is a working demo showing the whole thing in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/k6mkt/**

*I'm using a fake service here to mimic calling a web service in order to get the data. I highly recommend wrapping up your calls to `$http` in order to encapsulate data access in your controller.*

Comment: Well put Josh. I agree that one should encapsulate the data access layer, and love the idea of the fake service. However the delegation here is a bit strained in my opinion, and the code can get convoluted. It may be better to go all the way with refactoring and simply use an angular service dedicated for the purpose.

Comment: @EliranMalka - I actually did end up going all the way with the refactoring here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6R3zEX?p=preview

*That feels weird to say.*